# Retrieving signal strengh values from oncreate method

Tags: android, scope, signal-strength

how to retrieve the value of strengthAmplitude at oncreate method inside Activity.

```
 private class SignalStrengthListener extends PhoneStateListener
         {

     @Override

    public void onSignalStrengthsChanged(android.telephony.SignalStrengthsignalStrength) 
         {                        

             // get the signal strength (a value between 0 and 31)
             int strengthAmplitude = signalStrength.getGsmSignalStrength();


            super.onSignalStrengthsChanged(signalStrength);
          }
    }
```

Comment: Can you please tell us why it is required in onCreate() only? I just want to know the scenario.

Comment: yeah sure :) I want to implement database implemetation at oncreate() method.....

Comment: Can you move this logic to Application class of your app (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html) and pass strengthAmplitude variable to the Activity or keep reference of this variable any how like static/shared preferences..?

Comment: no....I am at the beginner level.... :P

Comment: Would u share something in the easiest way? thanks in advance...

Comment: Is there ny connection of database implemetation and "strengthAmplitude" variable and onCreate() of Activity?

Comment: yes...for that reason I need such a way....

Comment: please anybody give a clue atleast! really stucked on this!